# i want to fetch items at particular interval of time in android

Tags: android

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://www.rush.com/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);


        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

This is my code to view all product and it gives complete output . But each and every time i have to refresh manually to show new items...

Now i want to do auto refresh at every 10 seconds for retrieve all the product list....

so how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can user TimerTask. see [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

see example

```
if(timer != null){
     timer.cancel();
    }


//re-schedule timer here
//otherwise, IllegalStateException of
//"TimerTask is scheduled already" 
//will be thrown
timer = new Timer();
myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

if(optSingleShot.isChecked()){
 //singleshot delay 1000 ms
 timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000);
}else{
 //delay 1000ms, repeat in 5000ms
 timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000, 5000);
}
```

**Timer Class**

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
  }

 }

}
```

example [refer this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
```

use below one instead of abve one

```
new LoadAllProducts().execute(); //first time load
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setListAdapter(null);
                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
                }
            }, 10000);//you specify the particular time
```

Comment: it is shows continuously loading products, please wait... and it create duplicates of the product again....i want refresh after 1 minute but it is continuously loading products....

Comment: will you please tell me from where can i clear adapter?

Comment: @Boopathi...i have written this code...but it is only refreshed once......then it is wont refreshed it..and still same problem all product list occurs twice...

Answer (score 0):

You can try what given below -

Timer t;

t = new Timer();

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

```
private Context context;

@Override
        public void run() {

        // do your task that you want to refresh at reguler interval
               }


    },
        //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
            startdelay,
        //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
            timeinterval
    );
```